# Wordpress Category Filter not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am completely not sure if I am just being blind but not 100% used to wordpress as yet and would love some assistance with this.

I have my blog posts page showing all the blog posts it also has the categories in the sidebar but when a category is selected it changes the URI with the /categories/events but does not limit the posts content to what should be in the category?

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container posts">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
      <?php
        $args = array (
          'post-type' => 'post'
        );

        $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($post_query->have_posts())
          while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
            $post_query->the_post();
      ?>
      <div class="post">
        <?php
          the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );  
          echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
          the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
          echo '</a>';
          the_excerpt();
          echo do_shortcode( "[icon name='fa-calendar-o']" ) . " ";
          the_date("d F");
        ?>
      </div>
      <?php
          }
      ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? This is a full custom WP Theme from start to finish so I may be missing something very simple and if someone knows what that is I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: And where is the filter code?

Comment: Well, that code creates a brand new `WP_Query` object that retrieves all posts. This is not the typical way of doing things, which would be simply to use the existing `WP_Query` object that's been set up by WordPress and would have the right parameters to retrieve a Category's posts on a Category page... What's the filename of the template page you've posted?

Comment: @MattGibson The file name is index.php the home page is a seperate file name. I have never needed to do categories before so no clue on how to get something like this to work...

Comment: @PaulMurdoch WordPress would generally handle this for you automatically. Instead of creating a new `WP_Query` object, you should be able to just get rid of your `$post_query` object completely and use raw `have_posts()`/`the_post()` calls as explained in the [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) documentation. WordPress will use an existing query object that's already been set up appropriately for the kind of page you're displaying, based on its URL/parameters.

Comment: @MattGibson That worked! It is pulling through the categories perfectly now! Thank you man - If you post as Answer I will select +rep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before loading your `index.php` page, WordPress will have set up a `WP_Query` object for you according to the page URL/parameters. So on the main blog posts page, it will be a query that finds all posts; on the Foo category page it'll be a query that finds all posts in category Foo.

In your existing code, you're ignoring that pre-set-up query object and creating a new one, `$post_query`, that always just grabs all posts. That's why the results aren't changing when viewing a Category.

You should dump your specially-created `$post_query` object and use the basic WordPress "[The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)" code instead:

```
    if (have_posts())
      while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        ...
```

This will use the `WP_Query` object that's been set up for you by WordPress. Typically you don't create your own `WP_Query` object unless you're doing something a little out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thank you for assisting!